# How to test Cross Wire Welds

Tags: mechanical-engineering, welding

What is the best way to test the weld strength of a cross wire weld? For example, a wire grid with .212 dia wire x .212 dia wire. 
I cannot find any solid information online for testing cross wire welding (projection welding). I have seen a  picture of someone using a torque wrench to test individual intersections.

Answer (score 3):

The only test method I've seen is in the RWMA Resistance Welding Manual. They recommend the use of a pusher block and support to test the pull strength of cross wire welds. It is shown on page 6-5 of the revised 4th edition manual. There is also a reference table with weld strengths based on setdown and various weld parameters on the same page.